# Is this a correct use of pour?

Tags: grammaire

I wanted to translate "He is not allowed to go here" into French and I came up with the following, but I don't know which one is right

> Il n'est pas permis pour aller ici

Which to me looks ok.

> Il n'est pas permis d'aller ici

Which to me sounds like there's a rule to not go here.

And

> Il n'est pas permis à aller ici

I would appreciate if you explained why instead of a yes or no answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- "Là" instead of ici would be better for what you want to say ("aller" implying a place away from the speaker). [That post](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/12002/358) will explain this point.

2- You cannot use "pour" with "permettre".

3- You are confusing "permettre" and "avoir le droit de". In your sentences "il" represents an impersonal subject. Let's give "he" a name to make it clearer:

> Il n'est pas permis d'aller là.

It is not allowed to go there/ One is not allowed to go there.

> Je permets à John d'aller là. (Je lui permets d'aller là)

I allow John/ him to go there.

I think what you want is:

> John/Il n'a pas le droit d'aller là. 
>   John/ Il n'est pas autorisé à aller là.

Comment: Dans le contexte et les exemples donnés, ‘pour’ ne va pas avec ‘permettre’, mais est-ce que « pour **lui** permettre » serait permis des fois (en « John/Il n'a pas/manque l’autorité/diplôme nécessaire pour lui permettre d’aller/étudier ici », par exemple) ?

Comment: @PapaPoule Si on dit  « pour lui permettre » la préposition  *pour* introduit le complément de but qui contient *permettre* mais qui pourrait être un autre verbe, un nom... et ce n'est pas lié à l'emploi de *permettre*. De même si on emploi *pour* dans une expression de temps ("ce n'est pas permis pour l'instant"), c'est lié à l'expression de temps.

Answer (score 1):

**Les prépositions sont associées aux verbes (et plusieurs sont parfois possibles), expression par expression. Il faut soit les connaître, soit consulter un dictionnaire:**

En général, on peut souvent les faire suivre d'un groupe nominal / d'un substantif, ou d'un infinitif.

**Attention**: selon que l'on utilise un substantif ou un infinitif, les prépositions peuvent être nécessaires ou non, comme dans les exemples qui suivent:

> permettre + substantif : permettre une fête
>
> permettre de + infinitif : permettre de faire la fête
>
> autoriser + substantif : autoriser une fête
>
> autoriser à + infinitif : autoriser à faire la fête
>
> interdire + substantif: interdire la fête
>
> interdire de + infinitif : interdire de faire la fête

**Avec un COI, ou une personne visée par ces actions, c'est plus compliqué:**

> autoriser quelqu'un à + infinitif: autoriser Jacques à faire la fête
>
> permettre à quelqu'un (COI) de + infinitif : permettre à Jacques de
>   faire la fête
>
> interdire à quelqu'un (COI) de + infinitif : interdire à Jacques de
>   faire la fête

En règle général, les infinitifs sont introduits par *à* ou *de* dans ces constructions particulières à des verbes.

**Pour** est quelquefois utilisé en construction avec un verbe, mais assez rarement, avec un infinitif ou un substantif :

> remercier pour avoir fait quelque chose. (*de* est plutôt préconisé avec *remercier*).
>
> remercier pour ce cadeau, remercier de cet échange.

**Pour** est aussi utilisé avec un infinitif (**indépendamment** du verbe principal), pour construire un complément circonstanciel de but, ou avec un substantif :

> Pour faire de la musique, afin de faire de la musique.
>
> Pour la victoire de mon équipe.

Comment: Ton explication ne couvre pas le cas "Je me bats pour ma vie", par exemple, où "pour" n'introduit pas un infinitif ("avoir fait" dans ton exemple) mais un nom. Peux tu confirmer s'il s'agit d'une variante ou d'un cas complètement différent ?

Comment: @AnneAunyme, infinitif ou substantif, c'est le même usage avec pour, j'ai complété.

Answer (score 0):

Your translations are quite incorrect :

> He is not allowed to go here.

Would translate "Il n'a pas le droit d'aller ici".

Now for more details on your ideas. You are right in thinking that

> Il n'est pas permis d'aller ici

Means that there is a rule saying no one should go there.

The other sentences are wrong. The error comes from the fact that in French, "il" can take a general meaning : "it is not allowed to go there".

*Pour* would have no meaning in any close sentence, so it's a bit hard to explain. It would be akin to "He is not allowed to go for here"

*A* would be used with a different form :

> Il n'est pas autorisé à venir ici.

Here, I use *venir* (come) instead of *aller* (go) because the word *here* imply some closeness that translate better this way. 
I could use :

> Il n'est pas autorisé à aller là.

Where *là* is closer to *there* and imply some pointed place a bit farther.

Sorry for the messy presentation, smartphone typing is bad.

Comment: What if I use elle? will that be more understandable?

Comment: Elle is only for a feminine person or animal. It's really different meaning between expressing one person has no right to be some place or saying that no one should go there.